# Do you know what kind of bug this is?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I have tried to find a similar picture online, but can’t seem to find any.  Does anyone know what kind of bug this is?
It has been on a penstemon plant for about 3 days.

I am located just outside of Portland, Oregon.  It’s been on the same stem, only moved from one side to the other.  There have been about a few dozen honeybees around it, feeding on the flowers, and the bug hasn’t moved.  Also haven’t seen them feed on the plant.
Any ideas?

Body is similar to a ladybug, but I haven’t seen markings like this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please [edit] your post to include as much of the following essential information as you can — this will improve your chances of getting a good answer: 1) clear closeup photos of the organism (photos from multiple angles if possible); 2) the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where you observed this organism; 3) habitat information — e.g. what other plants are near; and 4) an estimate of the organism's size. ——— Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site for details.

Comment: You're welcome — since you don't seem to be getting much response here, you might want to try other sites that specialize in identification — (e.g.s: [iNaturalist](https://www.inaturalist.org/) and [BugGuide](https://bugguide.net/).

Answer (score 2):

#### Short Answer

Looks like the 4th [instar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instar) of *Thyanta custator*, the **Red-shouldered stink bug**, a type of [stink bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatomidae) found in Oregon.

[image]

<sup>[Oregon Dept. of Agriculture](https://www.oregon.gov/ODA/shared/Documents/Publications/IPPM/StinkBugGuide.pdf)</sup>

#### Long Answer

Definitely a nymph of some species of true bug (order [Hemiptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiptera)), most likely in the suborder [Heteroptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroptera) (i.e., the shield bugs, stink bugs, assassin bugs, etc.) and family [Pentatomidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatomidae).

For example, see these photos of nymphs of similar species:

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

<sup>From L->R: [*Podisus maculiventris*](http://www.austinbug.com/survey/2011/survey4-28-2011.html), [*Troilus luridus*](https://www.britishbugs.org.uk/heteroptera/Pentatomidae/troilus_luridus.html), [*Glaucias amyoti*](http://www.landcareresearch.co.nz/resources/identification/animals/pentatomidae/key-to-nymphs), [*Cosmopepla lintneriana*](http://www.toronto-wildlife.com/Insects/True_Bugs/Plant_bugs/true_bugs_stink.html), [*Carpocoris purpureipennis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpocoris_purpureipennis), [*Murgantia histrionica*](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/veg/leaf/harlequin_bug.HTM)</sup>

Using yet another species, *Piezodorus lituratus*, as an example, you can see how a Pentatomidae nymph typically develops to maturity:

[image]

<sup>[Source](http://picssr.com/tags/nymfa/interesting/page25)</sup>

As to your species...

Your specimen's physical appearance (i.e., black/white body with yellow band and centered red spot) appears to match that of the 4th instar of *Thyanta custator*, the **Red-shouldered stink bug**.

[image]

<sup>[Oregon Dept. of Agriculture](https://www.oregon.gov/ODA/shared/Documents/Publications/IPPM/StinkBugGuide.pdf)</sup>

From [Oregon Dept. of Agriculture](https://www.oregon.gov/ODA/shared/Documents/Publications/IPPM/StinkBugGuide.pdf):

> Nymphs are dark brown to black. Early nymphs have two distinctive pale spots on
> opposite sides of their abdomens and appear hairy compared to other stink bug nymphs. *Thyanta custator* is very closely related to *T. pallidovirens* and they are morphologically indistinguishable, but there is chromosomal evidence that they are separate species

- Your 2nd image does appear to have some "fuzziness" around the body's edge -- possibly this hairiness?

This species is listed as living in Oregon:

- Oregon's Dept. of Agriculture provides [this resource](https://www.oregon.gov/ODA/shared/Documents/Publications/IPPM/StinkBugGuide.pdf) showing common stink bugs found in your state. Species include: *Perillus bioculatus, Banasa dimidiata, Chinavia hilaris, Chinavia hilaris, Chlorochroa rossiana, Thyanta custator, Cosmopepla conspicillaris, Cosmopepla uhleri, Cosmopepla intergressa, Cosmopepla lintneriana, Holcostethus abbreviatus, Holcostethus limbolarius, Holcostethus tristis, Trichopepla aurora, Antheminia remota, Brochymena affinis, Brochymena quadripustulata, Euschistus conspersus, Euschistus variolarius, Halyomorpha halys*, and others as possible specimens.

[image]